# How to animate width using inline css

Tags: html, css, sass, vue.js

I'm trying to animate a width of an element using data from an API upon page load and I'm using Vue js. What I've done is I used inlined css and apply width value (from API data). I'm able to add the element width but it has no animation.

**Vue template edited:**

```
<li v-for="(stats, index) in teamStats[0]">
    <div class="bar">
        <span :style="'width:'+ stats +'%;'">
            {{stats}}
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Sass:**

```
.bar {
    span {
        text-align: $l;
        right: 0;
        width: 0%;
        -webkit-transition: width 1s;
        -moz-transition: width 1s;
        -o-transition: width 1s;
        transition: width 1s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `stats`?

Comment: I think you need to give like this style="{width: stats + '%' }"

Comment: stats has no initial initial value since I'm assigning it's value using a loop see above code

Comment: @HemaNandagopal I've tried your solution but doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried px intead of % ? <span style="{width: stats + 'px' }" >

Comment: yeah I've tried it but not working, no animation

Comment: You can use like: `data() {
  return {
    style: {
      width: 400,
    },
  };
}`

Comment: You can also use like: `v-bind:style="{ fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"` to get fontSize use: `data() {
  return {
    fontSize: 10
  }
}` Let me know if anyone works from above!

Comment: should I create a new method for that or just insert it inside :style @HirenGohel?

Comment: You can insert inside style

Comment: Is it works for you??

Comment: it doesn't animate @HirenGohel I've added data: { return { stats: 0} }

Comment: This is example: `<img :width="prefixedStyle">`  and to get width use: `data () {
    return {
      style: {
        width: 400,
      }
    }
  },`

Comment: Is it works now??

Comment: I cant make it work so I've created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/PenAndPapers/w4pLczuq/

Comment: Ok fine, you can learn more about it from here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-styles/

Comment: vanilla javascript is all you need - that's what it is there for. It allows you to tell the browser - "When this happens to that."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use the [JavaScript transition hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks). Here's an example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    stats: [],
  },
  
  created() {
    // Simulate loading data from server
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.stats = [0.1, 0.15, 0.32, 0.55, 0.88, 0.96];
    }, 500);
  },
  
  methods: {
    onEnter(el) {
      var stat = +el.dataset.stat;
      var index = +el.dataset.index;
      el.style.transitionDelay = index * 0.05 + 's';
      el.style.width = (stat * 100) + '%';
      el.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${50 - 50 * stat | 0}, 100%, 50%)`;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.bars {
  width: 400px;
}

.bar {
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar.v-enter-active {
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.bar.v-enter {
  /* Needs !important to override inline styles */
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0% !important;
  background-color: hsl(50, 100%, 50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition-group tag="div" class="bars" @enter="onEnter">
    <div class="bar" v-for="stat, index of stats" :key="stat" :data-stat="stat" :data-index="index">
      {{ (stat * 100 | 0) }}%
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```